# Why do I need an Inverter when converting a LCD screen to a standalone monitor

Tags: lcd, laptop-repair

I'm trying to convert a laptop screen into a standalone monitor to connect to a raspberrypi.

I have an old laptop lcd screen (LTN154X3-L03) and was planning to order this item to connect it to the raspberry pi:
[T.VST59(HDMI+AV+VGA+USB)Controller Driver Board Diy Kit for LCD/LED Screen Panel](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272086508548)

The description of the item mentions that it supports my screen but the problem is that this item seems not to have an "inverter".

The "inverter" seems to be present in most projects like this one...is it really needed? what is it for?

And is it possible that this item (T.VST59) has the inverter integrated in the board?

(I've asked the seller and they claim not to be technical and do not know.)

Comment: An *"inverter"* is a power supply that converts DC to AC.  A LCD panel should only need an inverter if it had CCFL lamps for its backlight.  (Of course it will always require DC supplies.) *"And is it possible that this item (T.VST59) has the inverter integrated in the board?"* -- No.  But there would be one in the laptop that the screen came from.  BTW you're probably posting this question at the wrong site.

Comment: now that I googled it a bit more, yes. I can see something that looks like an inverted in the laptop frame. But I don't think the interface /cable is the same. Do you think it will be possible for me to expand some wires out and connect the existing inverter into the controller's board?
Or...is it possible that this screen doesn't need an inverter at all? "only need an inverter if it had CCFL lamps for its backlight."

Comment: http://www.laptopscreen.com/English/screen-part-number/LTN154X3-L03/ indicates that there is one CCFL bulb.  Why are you speculating/guessing? If you have the panel, then visually inspect it yourself!

Comment: for future ref:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F0xPuz4Jnw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The "inverter" seems to be present in most projects like this one...is it really needed? what is it for?

An "inverter" is a power supply that converts DC to AC.
A LCD panel should only need an inverter if it had CCFL lamps for its backlight. (Of course it will always require DC supplies.)
(One site mentions that a LED backlight *could* have an inverter.)

> And is it possible that this item (T.VST59) has the inverter integrated in the board?

No, because (a) the controller's description would mention this additional capability, (b) a logic board (e.g. the controller) is rarely combined with a power supply (i.e. defeats concept of modularity), and (c) the requirements of the LCD screen would dictate the power capability of the inverter.

> Or...is it possible that this screen doesn't need an inverter at all?

No, several sites (e.g. http://www.panelook.com/LTN154X3-L03_SAMSUNG_15.4_LCM_overview_8697.html) state that the LTN154X3-L03 is a Samsung screen that has one CCFL bulb.

> Do you think it will be possible for me to expand some wires out and connect the existing inverter into the controller's board?

An inverter has to be properly powered, and not kludged onto any controller board.  You would need to adhere to any safety standards when extending wires and mounting boards.
The specifications for powering these devices are scarce, and maybe best obtained by actual measurement while in operation.